A question about reflection method of the wave equation
For the Wave Equation:

$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0 & x>0, t>0\\ 
u(x,0)=f(x) & x>0 &  \hspace{0.5cm} (1) \\ 
u_{t}(x,0)=g(x) & x>0 &  \hspace{0.5cm} (2)  \\
u(0,t)=0 & t>0  \\ 
\end{matrix}\right. $

The general solution is:

$ u(x,t) = \frac{f(x+ct)-f(ct-x)}{2}+ \frac{1}{2c}\int_{x+ct}^{ct-x}g(s)ds  $

In PDE of Strauss, to get this solution, he firstly odd extend the initial data, turn the problem to be a whole space problem and finally apply D'Alembert's formula.
My question is what if I use the zero extension instead of odd extension, I mean set
$$f_0(x)=0 \quad\forall x\le 0, \quad f_0(x)=f(x) \quad\forall x>0 $$
I can get another solution which is different from the first one, but the solution should be unique, where is the problem?

If you do it like that, your solution won't satisfy the boundary condition $u(0,t)=0$.

Yes, by the usual restrictions on start and boundary conditions at $$(x=0,x=\infty, x=0 \ \forall \ t>0 )$$ the solution is odd in in $x$ in order to fix the zero at $x=0$, if extended to $x\in \mathbb R$. By the trivial fact, that functions of $x\pm ct$ and their combinations solve the wave equation, given combinations are the solution.
A solution on the half space $x>0$,   decomposes the start conditions as a Fourir series of the odd sines, that fulfill the boundary condition and propagate of course, again, tetm by term,  by $x\pm ct$.
The Fourier decomposition of the velocity function $g$ is propagating into the forward light cone, and has to be antisymmetrized, too, to fit the boundary conditon.
Many  different representations of the same functions are always possible for linear systems by the freedom of choice of a basis.
